# How to fix executing espeak in python using subprocess

Tags: python, espeak

I am trying to execute espeak using python using an MBROLA voice "us1".

`from subprocess import call`

`call(["espeak","-v mb-us1","Hello, I am espeak"])`

and the following error appear'

> Failed to read voice ' mb-us1'

but it works fine with:

```
os.system("espeak -v mb-us1 'hello, I am espeak'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hava to split "-v mb-us1" in two list elements.

```
from subprocess import call

call(["espeak", "-v", "mb-us1", "Hello, I am espeak"])
```

The nth element of the list will be treated a the nth argument of the subprocess call.

In your case "-v mb-us1" was treated as a single argument instead of two seperate arguments.